# Join two table in Eloqouent return empty array, but when execute in raw query return value

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8, inner-join

i have table menus below

```
|    ID    | MENU     |
| -------- | -------- |
| 1        | Menu1    |
| 2        | Menu2    |
```

and table role_has_menu

```
| ROLE_ID  | MENU_ID  |
| -------- | -------- |
|    1     |    1     |
|    1     |    2     |
```

When i run query in SQL it return value (object) like table below

```
$query = "select * from "MENUS" inner join "ROLE_HAS_MENU" on "MENUS"."ID" = "ROLE_HAS_MENU"."MENU_ID" WHERE ROLE_ID='1'"
```

```
| ID |  MENU | ROLE_ID | MENU_ID |
| ---|-------|---------|---------|
| 1  | Menu1 |   1     |   1     |
| 2  | Menu2 |   1     |   2     |
```

but when i run eloquent in laravel 8, it return empty array

```
$query = DB::table('MENUS')->join('role_has_menu', 'menus.id', '=', 'role_has_menu.menu_id')->where('role_has_menu.role_id','=','1')->get();
```

it return:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#289 ▼
  #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

i've tried this code but it return empty array.

```
$query = DB::table('MENUS')->join('role_has_menu', 'menus.id', '=', 'role_has_menu.menu_id')->where('role_has_menu.role_id','=','1')->get();
```

i expect that query builder return value like this

```
| ID |  MENU | ROLE_ID | MENU_ID |
| ---|-------|---------|---------|
| 1  | Menu1 |   1     |   1     |
| 2  | Menu2 |   1     |   2     |
```